# How to set option bind for multiple "labels" in the window of the Tcl/Tk?

Tags: for-loop, label, tcl, bind, tk-toolkit

How to scan all `label` components within a `toplevel` or `frame` and set the option on the `bind` "<Enter>, <Leave> and <1>".

**See illustrative example:**

```
#!/bin/ash
# \
exec wish "$0" "$@"

package require Tk

wm withdraw .

toplevel .t -bg whitesmoke

wm geometry .t 240x180+0+0


###
######################## Begin Nav -> Menu -> Links ########################

label .t.l0 -bg whitesmoke -fg blue -cursor hand1 -text {Home}
label .t.l1 -bg whitesmoke -fg blue -cursor hand1 -text {Product}
label .t.l2 -bg whitesmoke -fg blue -cursor hand1 -text {Contact}
label .t.l3 -bg whitesmoke -fg blue -cursor hand1 -text {About}

    pack .t.l0 .t.l1 .t.l2 .t.l3  -side top -anchor nw

########################## End Nav -> Menu -> Links #########################
###

###
##### Open and Read Script File for "count/quantify labels" within File #####

    set fp [open "~/example.tk" r]

    set n 0

    set qtd {}

    while {[gets $fp line] > 0} {

            if [regexp -- label $line] {
                lappend qtd $line
            }

        incr n
    }      

    set total [llength $qtd]

    close $fp

####################### Ready! Total of Labels counted #######################
###

###
##### Scan labels exists within toplevel or frame and create bind numered ####

for {set i 0} {$i < [expr $total - 1]} {incr i} {
    set lbl .t.l$i
}

bind $lbl <Enter> {
    $lbl config -font {-family courier -size 9 -underline true}
}

bind $lbl <Leave> {
    $lbl config -font {-family courier -size 9 -underline false}
}

bind $lbl <1> {
    tk_messageBox -message "You choice: [$lbl cget -text]"
}

####################### End Scan of labels, and end block ####################
###
```

---

What I intend with this is to do something in the menu style of links used in web sites and blogs.

[image]

I've made countless unsuccessful attempts, so far I haven't been able to.

Can someone enlighten me how I can do it.

Comment: instead of a for-loop you should use [bindtags](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bindtags.html) it will make your code a lot simpler and efficient. Merry Xmas.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Thank you for commenting and taking the trouble to point out the source. Until then I was unaware of these `bindtags`, it was news to me. But, as I already had all the source code for my project I didn't want to change part of the logic and decided to keep looking for a solution and I found one. However, I promise to read with calm and study and practice `bindtags` now that I know it exists (by the way, Tcl/Tk is a little surprise box for me, it has many resources, syntax still unknown to me). And if, I get an answer with it, I will come back here to update mine. See you soon!

Comment: Try to work with the official documentation for [tcl commands](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/contents.html) and [tk commands](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/contents.html). If I try to find more examples than the docs has, I tend to look into the [wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/welcome) or try to make sense out of the available [TIP](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/index.md)`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve the same day I posted the question but, I waited to see if anyone else had any or vision of how to solve the problem giving here an answer, I waited to pass the Christmas party period 2022 for only now i came up with the answer.

---

After thinking a lot, and analyzing what could be done in relation to numbering the events of the binds, I was able to find a solution that is the one that I will show in the source code is well commented, identified and separated into blocks. So this clear and objective, being thus easy to read on the part of other developers / programmers. Follows:

```
#!/bin/ash
# \
exec wish "$0" "$@"

package require Tk

wm withdraw .

toplevel .t -bg whitesmoke

wm geometry .t 240x180+0+0


###
######################## Begin Nav -> Menu -> Links ########################

label .t.l0 -bg whitesmoke -fg blue -cursor hand1 -text {Home}
label .t.l1 -bg whitesmoke -fg blue -cursor hand1 -text {Product}
label .t.l2 -bg whitesmoke -fg blue -cursor hand1 -text {Contact}
label .t.l3 -bg whitesmoke -fg blue -cursor hand1 -text {About}

    pack .t.l0 .t.l1 .t.l2 .t.l3  -side top -anchor nw

######################### End Nav -> Menu -> Links #########################
###

###
########### Open and Read Script File for "count/quantify labels" within File ##########

    set fp [open "~/example.tk" r]

    set n 0

    set qtd {}

    while {[gets $fp line] > 0} {

            if [regexp -- label $line] {
                lappend qtd $line
            }

        incr n
    }      

    set total [expr [llength $qtd] * 4]

    close $fp

####################### Ready! Total of Labels counted #######################
####

###
######### Scan labels exists within toplevel or frame and create bind numered ########

set link {}

for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $qtd]} {incr i} {

    set lbl ".t.l$i"

    # on mouse over
    lappend link "bind+$lbl+<Enter>+{+$lbl+config+-font+{-family+courier+-size+9+-underline+true}+}"

    # on mouse out
    lappend link "bind+$lbl+<Leave>+{+$lbl+config+-font+{-family+courier+-size+9+-underline+false}+}"

    # on click
    lappend link "@bind+$lbl+<Button-1>+{+bell+;+clic+$lbl+}@"

    # used only whitespace line
    lappend link "#"
}

set fw [open "/tmp/bind-tags-events.src" w]

for {set n 0} {$n < $total} {incr n} {

    set cnt [lindex [split $link] $n]

    set lst [string map { "+" " " "{@" "" "@}" "" "#" "" } $cnt]

    puts $fw "$lst"
}

close $fw

##################### End Scan of labels, and end block ######################
###

###
############################ Source BindTags ############################

source /tmp/bind-tags-events.src

after 100 {

        file delete /tmp/bind-tags-events.src
}

########################### End Source BindTags ##########################
###
```

> Note that, I'm doing here is, 'for-loop' create the necessary binds for the events already numbered for each 'label' having as output to an external file named as **bind-tags-events.src** in the temporary directory -, **/tmp** (GNU/Linux operating systems), and I am incorporating the same file via 'source' and finally 'delete' it after being integrated into the 'script'

---

## Note

> The multiplier number is given by the number of `bind`s inside the `for-loop`, in our case we have **4**, so we use the arithmetic expression `[expr [llength $dir] * 4]`. If you increase or decrease the number of `bind` you put in to give effect to the `label` then this number must be different from **4**.

## Alert

If you was use this logic with some `glob`, so that way:

We have to create two separate **bind-tags-link.src** files. One for "Directories" and one for "Files". So it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/ash
# \
exec wish "$0" "$@"

... Code here 

###
##################### Begin: 1nd block - Folders ###################

set linkFolder {}

proc listFolder {} {

    # list only directories
    set dir [cd $env(HOME)]
    set dir [glob -nocomplain -directory $dir -type d -tails *.*]

    set total [expr [llength $dir] * 4]

    for {set i 0} {$i < $total} {incr i} {

        set lbl ".t.l$i"

        # on mouse over
        lappend linkFolder "bind+$lbl+<Enter>+{+$lbl+config+-font+{-family+courier+-size+9+-underline+true}+}"

        # on mouse out
        lappend linkFolde "bind+$lbl+<Leave>+{+$lbl+config+-font+{-family+courier+-size+9+-underline+false}+}"

        # on click
        lappend linkFolder "@bind+$lbl+<Button-1>+{+bell+;+clic+$lbl+}@"

        # used only whitespace line
        lappend linkFolder "#"
    }
}

listFoder

######################### End: 1nd block #########################
###

###
##################### Begin: 2nd block - Files ###################

set linkFile {}

proc listFile {} {

    # list only files
    set fl [cd $env(HOME)]
    set fl [glob -nocomplain -directory $fl -type f -tails *.*]

    set total [expr [llength $fl] * 4]

    for {set i 0} {$i < $total} {incr i} {

        set lbl ".t.l$i"

        # on mouse over
        lappend linkFile "bind+$lbl+<Enter>+{+$lbl+config+-font+{-family+courier+-size+9+-underline+true}+}"

        # on mouse out
        lappend linkFile "bind+$lbl+<Leave>+{+$lbl+config+-font+{-family+courier+-size+9+-underline+false}+}"

        # on click
        lappend linkFile "@bind+$lbl+<Button-1>+{+bell+;+clic+$lbl+}@"

        # used only whitespace line
        lappend linkFile "#"
    }
}

listFile

######################### End: 2nd block #########################
###

###
######################### Begin: 3nd block - Embed #########################

source /tmp/bind-folder-links.src 
source /tmp/bind-file-links.src

after 100 {
    foreach clear {bind-folder-links.src bind-file-links.src} {
        file delete /tmp/$clear
    }
}

############################# End: 3nd block ############################
###
```

For some, it may seem unnecessary to leave this message here, but I think it is very helpful for those who don't want to waste time trying to adapt it in case someone prefers to make such a list.